# Como usar un evento de un datagridview que fue implementado manualmente a punta de Código

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, programación-funcional

Si yo cree un DatagridView de esta forma:

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();

//DataTable is filled with values here...

DataGridView grid = new DataGridView();

foreach (DataColumn column in table.Columns)
{
grid.Columns.Add(column.ColumnName, column.ColumnName);
}

grid.DataSource = table;
```

Si quiero implementar el siguiente evento:

```
private void dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(object sender, 
DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
{
e.Control.KeyPress -= new KeyPressEventHandler(Column1_KeyPress);
if (dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 0) //Desired Column
{
    TextBox tb = e.Control as TextBox;
    if (tb != null)
    {
        tb.KeyPress += new KeyPressEventHandler(Column1_KeyPress);
    }
}
}
```

Como hago???

---

Cada evento me representa un método independiente que hace referencia al datagridView, pero como se hace esto si el datagridview se creo a punta de código en el método del load form???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aunque @Pikoh ya contestó, y es una respuesta correcta (y más apegada a tu pregunta), dejo una versión que me gusta mas, una versión ligeramente mas corta y es usando funciones lambda:

```
var grid = new DataGridView();

grid.EditingControlShowing += (s, e) => {
    e.Control.KeyPress -= new KeyPressEventHandler(Column1_KeyPress);
    if (dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 0) 
    {
        // te ahorras una línea si puedes usar c# 7.x
        if (e.Control is TextBox tb)
        {
            tb.KeyPress += new KeyPressEventHandler(Column1_KeyPress);
        }
    }
};
```

Me gusta porque el código no queda regado por todas partes, te vas al constructor y todo está ahí.

Comment: Muy buena respuesta. Esta es la forma mas limpia de hacerlo actualmente, pero como el OP ya tenía el método creado y parece novato, por eso le di mi respuesta. :)

Answer (score 2):

Para añadir un manejado de eventos se utiliza el operador `+=`. Por ejemplo, en tu caso sería así:

```
grid.EditingControlShowing += dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing;
```

después de crear el grid.

Mas información: [Suscribir y cancelar la suscripción a eventos](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/events/how-to-subscribe-to-and-unsubscribe-from-events#to-subscribe-to-events-programmatically):

> 1. Defina un método de controlador de eventos cuya firma coincida con la firma de delegado del evento.
> 2. Use el operador de suma y asignación (`+=`) para asociar el controlador de eventos al evento.